# Spring Boot MongoRepository ignoring validation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, validation, spring-boot

I have a Mongodb repository that is working fine:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "audits", path = "audits")
public interface AuditRepository extends MongoRepository<Audit, String> {
}
```

I have a bean, `Audit` that is:

```
@Data
@Document
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Validated
public class Audit {
    @Id private String id;

    @NotNull
    private Date start;

    @NotNull
    private Date end;
}
```

I'm using Lombok for getters/setters.

I expect the Repository to validate the `Audit` bean, but it saves an audit bean with `null` in the start and end date.

I added this to the `build.gradle`:

`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")`

How do I tell the REST service to use validation?  I don't see anything in `RepositoryRestConfiguration` that will turn it on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must import validations libs:

maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or gradle

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.4.2.Final'
```

and you must configure two beans:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener(LocalValidatorFactoryBean lfb) {
    return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(lfb);
}
```

Comment: So I updated the Hibernate version (Hibernate validator 6 does not work here) and fixed your code snippet and marked it as correct

Comment: In 2021 if you add the dependency it works with NotNull but not NotBlank (in which case it always fails). The rest of the answer looks about right though I copied my working code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292359/spring-data-mongodb-not-null-annotation-like-spring-data-jpa