# Define Mongo Schema Validation using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to define a **Collection in Mongo using Spring-boot with a JSON Schema validator option** (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#json-schema), I don't want a JSR-303 Bean validation (this is not a valid answer [Spring data mongoDb not null annotation like Spring data Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292359/spring-data-mongodb-not-null-annotation-like-spring-data-jpa)), but define, at the moment of the creation of the Collection, an option that is showed in the JSON using *CollectionInfos()*.

Example, if I define an Account model class likes:

```
public class Account {

@Id
private String id;

private String name;

private String surname;

@NotNull
private String username;
}
```

I want that the collection has, using *db.getCollectionInfos()*, a json likes:

```
[
{
    "name" : "account",
    "type" : "collection",
    "options" : {
        "validator" : {
            "$jsonSchema" : {
                "bsonType" : "object",
                "required" : [ 
                    "username"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "info" : {
        "readOnly" : false,
        "uuid" : UUID("979cdc4b-d6f3-4aef-bc89-3eee812773a5")
    },
    "idIndex" : {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "databaseName.account"
    }
}
]
```

The procedure could be similar to **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create**, because it defines rules at the schema level, and not similar to Bean validator, that defines rules at the Application level.

Comment: Schema Validation on the server in MongoDB is "really new" and the `$jsonSchema` "query operator" itself is really only a couple of months in circulation in the wild. Additions of "new features" to spring-mongo have been traditionally "slow paced", but it is however not an official MongoDB project and therefore a *"community labor of love"*. If you don't see a feature mentioned in the documentation, then it's not there. They might just accept a volunteered pull request

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BrentR I want that spring-data-mongo define automatically the JSON Schema starting from the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonSchema is supported by Spring Data MongoDB as of version `2.1`. Please see the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.jsonSchema) for details.
You can use a builder like below to define your schema.

```java
MongoJsonSchema schema = MongoJsonSchema.builder()
    .required("username")
    .properties(JsonSchemaProperty.string("username"))
    .build();

template.createCollection("account", CollectionOptions.empty().schema(schema));
```

At the time of writing json schema creation from a domain type is not support.
However you may want to join the discussion [DATAMONGO-1849](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1849) and/or give the snapshots of [PR#733](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/733) a try.

The suggestion would turn the `DomainType` into a `MongoJsonSchema` by calling something like `MongoJsonSchema schema = schemaCreator.createSchemaFor(DomainType.class);`

```java
public class DomainType {

    private final String requiredCtorArg;
    private final @Nullable String nullableCtorArg;
    private String optionalArg;

    public DomainType(String requiredCtorArg, @Nullable String nullableCtorArg) {

        this.requiredCtorArg = requiredCtorArg;
        this.nullableCtorArg = nullableCtorArg;
    }

    // gettter / setter omitted 
}
```

```
{
    'type' : 'object',
    'required' : ['requiredCtorArg'],
    'properties' : {
        'requiredCtorArg' : { 'type' : 'string' },
        'nullableCtorArg' : { 'type' : 'string' },
        'optionalArg' : { 'type' : 'string' }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Christoph, thank you for your reply! I have a question: why do you have decided to set **@Nullable** to define the NOT required parameters instead of define **@NotNull** parameters like in Hibernate? Also, is there any task in progress to support also the special keywords (like _pattern_ for String)?

Comment: Please let's discuss requirements/decisions for deriving the schema in the [issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1849).